# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n! e^n}{n^n}$ converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, analysis, power-series

i need some advice on how to prove if this series converges or diverges
tried using D'Alembert test but i received $1$ so it does not help me.
Thanks.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{n!e^n}{n^n}$$

Comment: Apply the root test.

Comment: $n^n$ grows much faster than $e^n$ because the exponents are the same and $n$ grows while $e$ is constant.

Comment: Was $n$ in the numerator supposed to be $n!$ by a chance?

Comment: @Wojowu yes i change it, somehow i forgot the facotorial notation.

Comment: Using [Stirling's Asymptotic Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), the terms are asymptotic to $\sqrt{2\pi n}$, so they do not go to $0$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^nn!}{n^n}$ diverges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787512/prove-that-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-fracennnn-diverges)

Comment: @MaorRocky  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3):

The series converges and we can see that in so many ways that is

- root test (maybe the simpler)
- ratio test (also effective)
- limit comparison test (for example with $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$)
- etc.

As an alternative, note that eventually, that is for $n\ge e^2$ we have $$n^n\ge e^{2n}$$ and since eventually $e^n \ge n^3$

$$\frac{ne^n}{n^n}\le\frac{ne^n}{e^{2n}}=\frac n{e^n}\le \frac{n}{n^3}=\frac1{n^2}$$

the given series converges by direct comparison test with $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The $n$th term equals

$$e\left(\frac{e}{n}\right )^{n-1}$$

and $e/n \le e/3$ for $n>2.$

Comment: slight correction needed: $e/n \le e/3$ for $n>2$ or $e/n < e/3$ for $n>3$

Comment: Right, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With some simple manipulations you can show that you can omit the factor $n$ in the numerator (are you able to do this?

Then you are left with $a_n=\frac{e^n}{n^n}$. To see that this sum converges it is enough to see, that these summands are smaller than lets say $\left(\frac{e}{10}\right)^n$, that is they are smaller than the summands of a (converging) geometric sum.

Answer (score 0):

With ratio test:
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=$$
$$\frac{n+1}{n} \frac{e^{n+1}}{e^n} \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=$$
$$e\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=$$
$$e\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n=$$
$$\frac{e}{n}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n \to 0$$
Because $\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n \to \frac{1}{e}$ and $\frac{e}{n} \to 0$

Comment: Hi everyone thanks for the help but the qustion was written wrongly, i added the (!) sign.